# What bytes to send to a telnet client from a Java server so the client does not show the password the user is typing?

Tags: java, security, sockets, terminal, telnet

I have a Java TCP server that receives a connection from a telnet client from a mac terminal. What byte sequence do I have to send to the client so the user will type the password in the telnet session and it won't be displayed in the terminal (echo off).

Then after the user has typed the password I want to turn the echo back on.

---

I am looking for a specific, correct and working answer, something like:

On the server side I will do:

```
client.send( byteArrayToTurnEchoOff )
```

then the user types the password, does not see it, server receives, and turn echo back on with something like

```
client.send( byteArrayToTurnEchoOn )
```

I am looking for `byteArrayToTurnEchoOff` and `byteArrayToTurnEchoOn` that works!

ANYONE?

Comment: Are you sure it's telnet? Telnet is a whole protocol which would need to be implemented by your server or you will get surprising results, not the least of which would be data loss.

Comment: Time to do some basic research.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854

Comment: (When you log in with ssh the character of the ssh password are not transmitted as such.)

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 857](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc857.txt) says `IAC DONT ECHO` and `ECHO` is option 1. [RFC 854](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc854.txt) says that is encoded as `255 254 1`.

The [vt100 User Guide](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/chapter5.html) gives this sequence (numbers are octal) to switch off terminal level echo (Send-Receive Mode (SRM)).

```
ESC  [   1   2   h
033 133 061 062 150
```

However, sending passwords unencrypted in 2014? Having not done this sort of thing since 2000, I have no idea how ssh handles this sort of thing.

`java.util.Console` has a `readPassword` method. I have no idea what that actually does on specific platforms.

Comment: Tom. See my edit. I can't understand or use your answer, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: ESC sequences could steer a terminal's behaviour. Your client is the terminal. @chrisapotek